# Table Not Found in H2 DB with Springboot Application with test yml file

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, h2, flyway

I am using postgrest, in sql script I have created table with schema.tablename syntax & used alter command with only "alter table tableName" syntax. I am using flyway. Now, I want to use H2 for Unit test purpose. But H2 doesn't find table when it execute alter table command. I believe this is due to no schemaName used in alter table syntax. Can anyone suggest a solution.?

Yml file:

```
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
      path: /h2
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MODE=PostgreSQL;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS test
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password: password
  jpa:
    generate-ddl: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
        show_sql: true
        format_sql: true
        use_sql_comments: true


SQL script: CREATE TABLE test.record (
  id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
  name character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  status character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  id bigint references test.details(id)
);

ALTER table record ADD column t_id character varying(50);

StackTrace:
Migration of schema "PUBLIC" to version 4 - AlterRecord Table failed! Please restore backups and roll back database and code! [main] []

[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$FlywayMigrateException: 
Migration V4__AlterRecord_Table.sql failed
-----------------------------------------------
SQL State  : 42S02
Error Code : 42102
Message    : Table "record" not found; SQL statement:
ALTER table record ADD column t_id character varying(50) [42102-197]
Location   : db/migration/V4__AlterRecord_Table.sql (D:\Test\testProject\impl\target\classes\db\migration\V4__AlterRecord_Table.sql)
Line       : 16
Statement  : ALTER table record ADD column t_id character varying(50)
 [main] []
```

Comment: Please provide your db.migration sql file content, the test yaml file, and the stack trace.

Comment: @StavShamir Provided in edit.